# Can I extract an overwriting tar archive, while retaining the ownership of the original destination file(s)?

Tags: permissions, tar, root, archive, ownership

I have a particular use case, where I want to extract a tar archive (as root) and intentionally overwrite some destination file(s) with the contents of the archive. This is all fine and easily achievable, but I also want to retain the original ownership and permissions of the original destination file(s). As an example:

`$ touch file && tar cf test.tar.gz file &&
  sudo chown www-data:www-data file &&
  sudo tar xf test.tar.gz && ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim 0 May  1 11:26 file`

Here I create a file as my user (`tim:tim`), archive it, change its ownership to `www-data:www-data`, then (as root) extract the archive, overwriting the original file. As you can see, its ownership has been modified to that of the file in its pre-archived state, whereas post extraction, I want it to be owned by `www-data:www-data`.

I've had a fairly close look at the `tar` man page, but can't see an immediately obvious way to do what I want. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

As a normal user, you wouldn't be able to overwrite the file owned by www-data with only write permissions for the owner, so what you want couldn't work in your example.

What would work, if your user is permitted to write to these files, is to use `--overwrite`. However you will get errors when `tar` tries to change the modification time and permissions of the file, because again you as a regular user aren't permitted to do that to files that don't belong to you.

Comment: (Good point, I should have a sudo on the `tar xf` too. I was doing the test in a directory I owned, so this wasn't necessary.)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how `--overwrite` helps here. Overwriting the file isn't the problem; that happens by default. What I'm trying to avoid is that the overwrite changes the metadata of the extracted file to those that are stored in the archive, whereas I want to retain the metadata of the file before it was overwritten. Ultimately I can come up with some elaborate solution that saves the file's metadata pre-extract, and restores it post-overwrite, but I was hoping I could get `tar` to do that for me.

Comment: Without `--overwrite` it will *replace* the file, i.e. first removing it and thus losing the current owner. But maybe you're better off using `pax` instead of `tar`

Comment: Ah, that's a subtlety I hadn't appreciated. I had not heard of `pax` before; I'll give it a look. Though one of the issues in my particular situation is that I am (fairly safely, one would think) assuming `tar` is available on the machines on which the script will execute. Is `pax` as widely deployed?

Comment: `pax` might not be installed by default but it should be readily available from whatever distribution you use.

Comment: Unfortunately the use case here is running a script on an unknown remote machine, in order to upgrade some software. FWIW, in the end I went with `RESTORE_METADATA=$(stat -c"chmod %a ${TARGET} && chown %U:%G ${TARGET}" ${TARGET}) && ... && eval ${RESTORE_METADATA}`